# From definition of a function, are range values a subset of $Y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two nonempty sets. A function from $X$ into $Y$ is a relation that associates with each element of $X$ exactly one element of $Y$
>
> [...] Since there may be some elements in $Y$ that are not the image of some $x$ in $X$, it follows that the range of a function may be a subset of $Y$. [*Precalculus*, Sullivan 9th edition, Pg. 47]

When stated "the range of a function may be a subset of $Y$," does this mean $Y$ is a set of all real numbers, making the set of range values a subset of $Y$?

Would $X$ also be a set of real numbers as well, making the domain values a subset of $X$?

Comment: The way to think about the range is the set of all values in the codomain that are mapped to by the function. Consider the function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ given by $n\mapsto 2n$. The codomain is clearly $\mathbb N$, but the range is the set of all elements mapped to by the function, i.e., the even positive integers. Another way to think about it is that the range is the largest subset of the codomain over which the function is well-defined, or that it is a restriction of the codomain that makes the function surjective.

Comment: Since you're dealing with Precalculus material, I think the author means that $X$ and $Y$ are the Reals or some subsets. In general, $X$ or $Y$ maybe Complex, real or even multi-dimensional ($\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$). The best way to understand the concept of domain, co-domain and range is to see what a function does. It takes a value from the domain (in this case $X$), and assigns it to a value in $Y$. The range is the set $\{f(x):x\in X\}$. So, if we can get all values of $Y$ using the function, the range would just be $Y$, otherwise it would be a subset.

Comment: The range of a function is always a subset of the codomain.   The domain and the codomain can be any not empty set.  For example, the domain can be the guests of a hotel and the codomain can be the guest's name.